# Insert the value of an argument into the legend

Tags: r, legend

I am trying to write a function with a graph-output.
I would like to insert a legend with a value of the argument.

For example:

```
f<-function(x,alpha=0.9){
   ....
   plot(x)
   legend("topleft",expression(alpha)???)
   }
```

'expression(alpha)' should equal the current value of alpha.

Can anyone tell me how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a test case yet, but the usual answer to this sort of question (where one portion of an expression needs to be evaluated) is `bquote` with its built-in `.()` function:

```
f<-function(x,alpha=0.9){ .... plot(x) legend("topleft", bquote(.(alpha)) ) }
```

The `.() function isolates the section(s) that deserve evaluation. See also the plotmath page:

```
?plotmath
```

Sometimes `substitute` is needed:

```
 alpha=0.2
 substitute( alpha, list(alpha=alpha) )
 #0.2
```

.... but most people find `bquote` easier to work with.

The addtional code requested with some editing to avoid overwriting label1:

```
x<-seq(0,60,length=150) 
 y<-rnorm(150,0,10) 
 yy<-x+y 
 d<-cbind(x,yy) 
 m<-lm(d[,2]~d[,1]) 
 plot(x,yy) > abline(m) 
 label1<-summary(m)$'r.squared' 
 label2<-summary(m)$'adj.r.squared' 
 legend("topleft", legend=bquote( R^2==.(label1)*";"~Adj.R^2==.(label2) ) )
```

Comment: Hello DWin and thank You!
I have managed to insert one thing, but i would like now to insert two things over each other, e.g. R-Squared and Adj-R-Squared.
I don't know how to finish the code:
> x<-seq(0,60,length=150)
> y<-rnorm(150,0,10)
> yy<-x+y
> d<-cbind(x,yy)
> m<-lm(d[,2]~d[,1])
> plot(x,yy)
> abline(m)
> label1<-summary(m)$'r.squared'
> label1<-summary(m)$'adj.r.squared'
> legend("topleft",legend=bquote(???))

[sorry for my ugly text, i also have to learn this kind of coding :)]

Comment: Sigh. It would be a lot easier if you had posted tested code in your question body. Kind of pain to replace all the ">" with carriage returns. Considerate programmers respect the laziness of other programmers.

Comment: The two expressions are now in one line. Is it also possible to depict R^2 and adj. R^2 over each other?

Comment: There is an `over` function in plotmath.

Comment: Ok, i found it:
....
legend("topleft", legend=bquote(atop (R^2==.(label1),Adj.R^2==.(label2) ) ))